# 28 Core Mac Pro Build times slow

Tags: xcode, performance

Extremely slow build times on my new Mac Pro 28 core.   I notice 2 symptoms.    High System CPU usage (80% versus 20% user) and overall the system CPU usage doesn't seem to often get higher them 30%.

Xcode 11.3, I am using buck currently to compile (with a really high thread count)

How do I debug what is using the system cpu?    In activity monitor, nothing represents the System Usage appropriately.

Comment: Instruments.app can help if your build is at fault. Find it via spotlight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments. ... [28-Core Mac Pro build time significantly worse than Macbook Pro \[closed\]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378081)

Comment: Have you selected 'All Processes' instead of 'My Processes' in Activity Monitor?